# Displaying the first category from a custom taxonomy with get_the_terms

Tags: wordpress

I have setup a custom post type with a custom taxonomy as categories.

I need to use `get_the_terms` or `wp_get_post_terms` to return the first category of a post in the custom post type.

But I can't quite figure out how to use it in comparison to `get_the_category`.

Answer (score 1):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

This is a very useful resource, if you are within the loop already it will return an array of categories.
To access the first one you could assign the array to a variable and call the first one.

```
$arr = wp_get_post_terms();
$first = $arr[0];
```

Or the last

```
$last = array_pop((array_slice($arr, -1)));
```